# How can I load profiles.clj into CURSIVE REPL?

Tags: clojure, cursive

My profiles.clj file starts with:

```
{:dev
    {:env {:env-name
```

How do I load it in CURSIVE REPL in order for me to be able to use `(:env-name env)` in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The content of `profiles.clj` is not available to your REPL session. But you can read the file yourself:

```
(ns mastering.stackoverflow
    (:require
        [clojure.tools.reader.edn :as edn]))

    (-> ".....path...../profiles.clj "
        (slurp)
        (edn/read-string)
        :dev
        :env)
```